# Remote shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, ssh, remote-access

I am wanting to write a script which I can use to grep for a process on a remote server,
on each server there is already a user account which can ssh with out a password,
so the idea is this script will

- sudo to passwordless user account
- ssh to remote server
- run commands (ps -ef | grep processname)
- display the output on the local server
- close the ssh connection
- exit out of passwordless user account

at the minute I have:

```
if [ $1 = -r ]
then
su - useraccount
ssh $2 "ps -ef | grep process | grep -v grep"
exit
else
ps -ef | grep process | grep -v grep
fi
```

The idea here is you can run the script locally if you dont have the -r option
so to run locally you would have

```
script.sh processname
```

or remotely

```
script.sh -r remotehost processname
```

I have the grep -v grep in there becasue it just annoys me seeing my own grep command in the list,
I just think it looks a bit cleaner
Any ideas?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: `su` starts its own shell, use `su - username -c "your ssh command"`.

Comment: Thanks yes that worked, i can get the script to ssh onto the remote server but now the problem is passing the local variables to the remote server, so if i run `script.sh -r remotehost processname` the processname is $3 locally but not remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saying

```
ssh -t host command $argument ...
```

say

```
ARGUMENT="-abc"
COMMAND="'command $ARGUMENT'"
```

and then offer

```
sst -t host $COMMAND
```

the remote machine is going to have no idea what `$ARGUMENT` is, so be sure to interpolate that string on the local machine before sending it. Note that you will need to be tricky with quotes, as I have, above, because you cannot interpolate variables inside single ticks (`''`).

edit:

I have to wonder why you are insisting on running the pipes on the remote machine. Can you not simply say:

```
ssh -t host -- ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep
```

That seems to me the best way to do this. Then you don't have to mess around with variable interpolation and and curious ticks.

edit 2:

Can you not just use `sudo -s username ssh foo`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of processing and piping to do, I would recommend writting a script at local host and then invoke it on remote host with ssh.

> localhost $ `cat localScript.sh`
>   #!/usr/bin/ksh`

`ps -ef | grep -i java | grep -v grep`

> localhost $ `ssh remotePassword@remotehostname < localScript.sh`

This will print the expected output on local host.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to switch to a different user locally to be able to login as that user on a remote system.

```
ssh -l <username> remotemachine
```

So:

```
ssh -l useraccount remote host ps -ef | grep process
```

Do the grep locally, and you avoid the problem with grep appearing in the output as well.